# Strange UIImage problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

My app takes an image from UIImagePicker and displays it but after scrolling through the images in a uiscrollview a few times, an image can mostly not be displayed, replaced with blank spots where it should be instead. After that various ui elements can disappear, for example other uiimages, and the time on the phone lock screen until the app's closed.

I'm unsure how to describe this to well, maybe it'll ring a bell with someone. It only happens when the uiimages are added to subview.

Comment: Hard to diagnose the problem without seeing parts of your code mate.
Are you releasing something too early? (unlikely as it'd prob crash on a dealloc error but it's a guessing game without parts of the code)

Comment: no, no errors, just on-screen glitches. blocking out various different parts of code has no effect, other than the 'addSubview:' line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and took me some times to figure it out. But the actual answer is pretty easy. Look at the "`size inspector`" and check "`autoresizing`" for your `UIImageView`. It changes the way your `UIImageView` is positioned and sized after you use a scroll.